# LARGEADDRESSAWRAE disabled after running CI job for .NET Application

Tags: c#, .net, security

I am testing LARGEADDRESSAWRAE for .Net Applications. I have a sample project of class library type. When I build this project in Visual Studio 2017, I can see that LARGEADDRESSAWARE is enable using **dumpbin**.
When we build our project in automation (jenkins) then LARGEADDRESSAWARE goes disabled. I want to know why this is happening?

Note: My Building solution configuration are Release|Mixed Platforms.